# eliminar elementos de una nodeList javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes a todos.

tengo una nodeList :

```
document.querySelectorAll(div)

[0: 1div
1: 2div
2: 3div
3: 4div]
```

lo que quiero hacer es poder eliminar 3 de los 4 elementos que tengo, poder solo dejar la posicion 0 de mi NodeList.

¿Podrian ayudarme?

Comment: Hola, podrías dar mas detalles? ¿cuál es el criterio para eliminar los elementos de la lista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para realizar este proceso basta con leer un poco la documentación oficial de NodeList [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList); básicamente puedes lograr lo que quieres con dos funciones nativas: **for() y remove()**.

Aquí el código:

```
let myDivList = document.querySelectorAll("div");
let count = 0;
for (item of myDivList){
    if(count > 0){
        console.log("Se removerá el div:", item);
        item.remove();
    }
    count += 1;
}
```

Al iniciar el recorrido del bucle se dejará intacto el primer elemento de la lista, pero en las iteraciones posteriores se irán eliminando los demás elementos gracias a la condición que tenemos, puesto que cada vez se aumenta el contador de uno en uno.

Espero sea lo que buscas.

Comment: `remove` no es una propiedad, es un método, se ejecuta con los paréntesis: `Element.remove()`

Comment: @MerlingSamuelSobalvarro Gracias, no noté el error.